# Jsoup Login to "https://www.mygolf.de/"

Tags: java, authentication, web, jsoup

I am currently trying to login to "https://www.mygolf.de/" via jsoup to parse the data from that page.
But I am having a hard time in finding the right way how to login an parse that data.
Can anyone help me with my troubles?

Thank for anyone helping!

Comment: you should probably use Selenium for this kind of stuff. JSoup is only recommended for parsing HTML, not interacting with it

Comment: Thanks that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using **Selenium** (http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Thanks to @Chandler Bing for suggesting it!